# how to search list of dictionary values with pandas dataframe series column elements

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, search, lambda

I have a dictionary & data frame column which has a series of list elements in string type.

if values in dictionary item are matched with any of string elements that should be marked with the itemname

for ex: input

```
text_column=[['grapes','are','good','for','health'],['banana','is','not','good','for','health'],
['apple','keeps','the','doctor','away'],['automobile','industry','is','in','top','position','from','recent','times']]

dict={ "fruit_name":['apple','grapes','lemon','cherry'],
        "profession":['health','manufacturing','automobiles']
     }
```

output :

```
    1) fruit_name
    2) fruit_name
    3) profession
    4) profession
```

Comment: Any particular part of this you are stuck on? It's a very broad question with just "How do I code this complex requirement". As for the question, `[grapes,are,good,for,health]` contains strings from both `fruit_name` and `profession`, which one wins? Also, your `text_column` has 4 rows however your output only has 3? Not much of this is understandable. Please narrow the focus of your question, include code you have attempted, and make the code understandable.

Comment: please provide valid python code

Comment: @JNevill Forgive I forgot to mention 4th-row output while writing. text column has multiple lists of elements it should filter if the same element found in dict values

Comment: @JNevill : I tried with lambda function but few elements are not getting mapped/matched/filtered with dict values .  this is the code df['text_column'].apply(lambda list: [dicts.get(item) for item in list if item in dicts.items()])

Comment: df['filter_values']=df['text_column'].apply(lambda list: [dicts.get(item) for item in list if item in dicts.items()])

Comment: @mozway : please see the above code I have tried like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse `dict` to create `reverse_dct` and `map` words in `'text_column'` to `'word_type'` (by the way, `dict` is a dictionary constructor in Python, don't name your variables `dict`).

```
reverse_dct = {}
for k,v in dct.items():
    for i in v:
        reverse_dct[i] = k

df = pd.DataFrame({'text_column':text_column})
df['word_type'] = df['text_column'].explode().map(reverse_dct).dropna().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
```

Output:

```
                                         text_column              word_type
0                   [grapes, are, good, for, health]  fruit_name,profession
1               [banana, is, not, good, for, health]             profession
2                  [apple, keeps, the, doctor, away]             fruit_name
3  [automobile, industry, is, in, top, position, ...                    NaN
```

Note that the last row doesn't have a type because you have `automobiles` in `dict` but `automobile` in `text_column`. You'll need to normalize spelling if you want your program to recognize these are the same.